# How to calculate the Amount in a selected rows on Datagridview - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

how to calculate the amount of Selected rows in my table

I only want to calculate the to Total amount with the Status of Printed = 'Y' and Receive = 'N'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDqPE.png

Heres my code, this code will only calculate the total of Column amount

```
Dim rows As Integer = 0
Dim total_amount As Double

Try
    Do Until rows = DataGridView1.RowCount
       Dim AMOUNT = DataGridView1.Rows(rows).Cells(1).Value
       total_amount = total_amount + AMOUNT
       rows = rows + 1
    Loop
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

lblAmount.Text = total_amount
Dim dblValue As Double = total_amount
lblTotalWithheld.Text = (dblValue.ToString("N",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something for every row in the grid then loop through the `Rows` collection, e.g.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    'Use row here.
Next
```

If you want to do something for each selected row then loop through the `SelectedRows` collection, e.g.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    'Use row here.
Next
```

You say:

> how to calculate the amount of Selected rows in my table

but it's not clear whether you mean selected in the UI or with the specified values in the specified columns.  Either way, the code inside the loop will be the same:

```
If CStr(row.Cells(0).Value) = "Y" AndAlso CStr(row.Cells(1).Value) = "N" Then
    Dim amount = CDbl(row.Cells(2).Value)

    'Use amount here.
End If
```

I've used arbitrary column indexes there, so you should change them as required.

EDIT:

If your actual criteria for processing involves the state of the data rather than the state of the UI then you should actually not be using the grid at all, but rather the data source.  If you aren't already, you should start by populating a `DataTable`, binding that to a `BindingSource` and then binding that to the grid, e.g.

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

You can then loop through the `BindingSource` to get the desired data, e.g.

```
Dim amount As Double = 0

For Each rowView As DataRowView In myBindingSource
    If CStr(rowView("Printed")) = "Y" AndAlso
       CStr(rowView("Receive")) = "N" Then
        amount += CDbl(rowView("Amount"))
    End If
Next
```

You could even throw some LINQ at it:

```
Dim amount = myBindingSource.Cast(Of DataRowView)().
                             Where(Function(drv) CStr(drv("Printed")) = "Y" AndAlso
                                                 CStr(drv("Receive")) = "N").
                             Sum(Function(drv) CDbl(rowView("Amount")))
```

or, in query syntax:

```
Dim amount = (From drv As DataRowView In myBindingSource
              Where CStr(drv("Printed")) = "Y" AndAlso
                    CStr(drv("Receive")) = "N")
              Select CDbl(rowView("Amount"))).Sum()
```

Possibly the easiest option of all, though, is to use the `Compute` method of the `DataTable`, e.g.

```
Dim amount = CDbl(myDataTable.Compute("SUM(Amount)",
                                      "Printed = 'Y' AND Receive = 'N'")
```

Comment: I only want to calculate the to Total amount with the Status of Printed = 'Y' and Receive = 'N'

See the image for reference

Comment: Gee, I wonder whether that would explain why the last code snippet in my answer tests whether one column contains "Y" and another contains "N".  Did you even bother to read the answer?  Also, if that's your criteria for processing then it has nothing to do with selection, so that was a red herring.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer that may be of interest.

Comment: `CStr`, `CDbl` - please, you are writing vb.net code ;)

Comment: @Fabio, I'm not sure but you seem to be implying that the use of `CStr` and `CDbl` is using VB6-style code, but it's not.  That's simply how you cast in VB.NET.  `CStr(var)` is simply a shaorthand for `CType(var, String)`.  Normally I would use `DirectCast` rather than `CType` but the shorthand versions of `CType`, including `CStr` and `CDbl`, produce more succinct code.  I do use `DirectCast` for everything else though.

Comment: You are right about my "implying" :), I prefer to use `DirectCast`, because `DirectCast` is very strict operator and will cast only when original value is already of type you are targeting, this will provide useful information to the readers of your code.

Comment: thank you so much, i already solved my problem, what i use is to loop through the BindingSource.